# To have a cronjob triggered both daily and upon reboot, do I need two separate jobs?

Tags: command-line, bash, cron, reboot

I have a line in the cronfile like this.

```
@daily cd Model_Pipeline && bash deploy.sh>>deployment.log 2>&1
```

It is running everyday just fine, but I also want it to run upon every reboot as well. Do I have to add another line, or is there a way to add an OR clause to the existing line (which seems a cleaner method)?

Also, I am not a root user. Does it hinder running the job at reboot?

Comment: Of the top of my head yes, you will need 2 lines. Look at the command `anacron`. This may do what you want.

Comment: adding @reboot will have it run twice when you start your machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to add a second line with the `@reboot` trigger.

```
@reboot cd Model_Pipeline && bash deploy.sh>>deployment.log 2>&1
```

And it's perfectly fine to run cronjobs `@reboot` with your normal user.